# Problem in writing Firebase Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document named 'PublicList' that can be read by anyone in a collection. However I want to allow read to the rest of the documents in that collection only if request.auth != null. However it is not working.

This is the code:

```
 match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if user == 'PublicList';
        allow read, write: if user != 'PublicList' && request.auth != null;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second `read` will override the first. Can you try this?

```
match /users/{user} {
  allow read: if (user == 'PublicList' || (user != 'PublicList' && request.auth != null));
  allow write: if user != 'PublicList' && request.auth != null;
}
```

'PublicList' can be read by everyone. Any other document can be read by authenticated users only.

No documents can be written except 'PublicList' and that too by an authenticated user.